# Is there a current way to create a discord channel then select it later on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Currently, I have been working on a Discord.js bot for a discord server I have. I want to make a command so that a user can open a ticket using `!oticket` and it will make a new channel that all of their dms to the bot will come through. I have working code for the channel creation, but when I tried to add an `if` statement to make it so that if someone has a ticket already opened they couldn't open another one, I couldn't find a working way to select a channel by its name.

Here is my current code:

```js
var test = msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === msg.author.username); //Outputs null even if a channel with their username already exists
    console.log(test);
    if (!msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === msg.author.username)) { // Passes even if a channel with their username already exists
        
    var server = msg.guild; //Works fine
    var name = msg.author.username; //Works fine

    server.createChannel(name, { //Works fine
        type: "text",
        parent: client.channels.get("834963781342724096"),
        
    }); //Works fine
        
    } else {
        msg.reply("You already have an open ticket!")
    }
```

I know that finding a channel by its name is impractical but this bot will only be on my server.

Comment: find() returns `undefined` whenever a channel is not found, in some cases your argument for the if-statement may be evaluating to `!undefined`, which itself evaluats to `true` causing the if-statement to fire

Comment: @Elitezen I tried changing it to ` if (msg.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "plustv") !== undefined || null) {` but it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a map where you can set a value when the user has created a ticket what would look like this:

```
const ticketmap = new Map();


if(ticketmap.get(msg.author.id)) return message.reply(`You already have an open ticket!`);
    
var server = msg.guild; //Works fine
var name = msg.author.username; //Works fine

server.createChannel(name, { //Works fine
    type: "text",
    parent: client.channels.get("834963781342724096"),
    
}).then(ch => {
    ticketmap.set(msg.author.id, ch.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array#find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is intended to return the first result that matches the given function, *undefined* if nothing is found. What you're looking for is a boolean, in this case use [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

You also forgot to acces the `cache` property for `msg.guild.channels`

```
const channelExists = msg.guild.channels.cache.some(c => c.name === msg.author.username);

if (!channelExists)) {
   var server = msg.guild;
   var name = msg.author.username;

   server.createChannel(name, {
       type: "text",
       parent: client.channels.get("834963781342724096") 
   }); 
} else {
   msg.reply("You already have an open ticket!");
}
```

Comment: Since they're using `server.createChannel()`, I'm sure they're using v11